# Capture Events From Microsoft.Identity.Web Login/Logout

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware, microsoft-identity-web

I am using Microsoft's Authentication/Authorization platform to allow User Sign-ins from Azure AD. I would like to log these events into a database. Issue is, since this type of authentication leverages middleware I am not sure how to inject code to trigger a log event.

Please let me know if there exists documentation I haven't yet found and/or how to write up a custom injection to log these events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. For any potential usefulness to anyone else in the future I will add what I did below..

I set up my database according to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

I created this Middleware Class

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Application.Models;
using Application.Data;

namespace Application.Middleware
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class EventLogCaptureMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly EventLogContext _context;

        public EventLogCaptureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, EventLogContext context)
        {
            _next = next;
            _context = context;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var eventLogModel = new EventLogViewModel
            {
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Type = "TEST",
                Method = httpContext.Request.Method,
                Upn = httpContext.User.Identity.Name,
                Resource = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}{httpContext.Request.Path}"
            };
            _context.Add(eventLogModel);
            var tasks = new Task[] { _context.SaveChangesAsync() };

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class EventLogCaptureMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseEventLogCaptureMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<EventLogCaptureMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

And injected into Startup.cs likeso:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //Production Exception Handler ex: API connection failed will trigger exception routed to /Home/Error
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //Handles User Error: 401, 403, 404, etc. Errors caught must land Application side. Errors occured in API with return 500 and be routed via Exception Handler
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?status={0}");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            //Must include Authentication/Authorization under routing
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEventLogCaptureMiddleware();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```